# Node.js & Mongoose sorting problems

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, sorting

I'm trying to sort two articles by descending date. Can't undersand, why it doesn't sort it right.

My dates: `2016-05-17T09:59:00.000Z, 2017-05-03T10:00:00.000Z`

My sorting mechanism: `return this.model.find(parameters.filter).sort({createdAt: -1}).limit(parameters.top);`

Where model is just mongoose.model.

Haven't got any idea what's wrong with it :( Appreciate your help!

My mongoose schema:

```
mongoose.Schema({
  title: String,
  summary: String,
  createdAt: Date,
  author: String,
  content: String
});
```

Here you can see how my articles are shown: https://ibb.co/j3kodF

Comment: Define "not sorting right". Also, which version of Mongoose?

Comment: Mongoose v.4.9.8.
It must show article with the second date, then with the first. It's shown in reversed order.

Comment: That would be an ascending sort. You told it to sort descending.

Comment: I've just added a date and printed it with the same sorting. And here is the result: 
2017-05-22T09:59:00.000Z,
2016-05-17T09:59:00.000Z,
2017-05-03T10:00:00.000Z.

Comment: Last time I checked `22 - 17 - 03` ( which are the days ) **is** descending order. Possibly you are focusing in on the hours and not looking at this properly.

Comment: And how should I sort it properly?

Comment: Please look at those dates again "carefully" What I just said was that they are correctly returning in the descending order just like you asked them to. There is nothing wrong with the query or results. It's just you who are reading the results wrong. That's how it looks to me anyway.

Comment: @NeilLunn The years are ascending. But we need more info here to help. Nikita, can you [edit] your question to show your schema and a couple sample documents that reproduce the problem?